# How to animate camera in React three fiber without lookAt()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am trying to animate a camera movement so that when a user clicks on the contact menu, the 3D model shows on the left of the screen. Something like [this project](https://hoang.moe/)

Currently, I'm using the UseFrame hook as in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@zmommaerts/animate-a-camera-in-react-three-fiber-7398326dad5d)

The problem is I'm using the lookAt() function and the 3D element is always in the center of the screen.

Here's my code

```
import { useAnimations, useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { useControls, button} from 'leva'
import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Vector3 } from 'three'

export default function Character ({isContact}) {

    const character = useGLTF('./model.gltf')
    const { actions } = useAnimations(character.animations, character.scene)
    
    const markerRef = useRef()
    const vec = new Vector3()
    
    useFrame((state, delta, xrFrame) => {
        
        if(isContact){                           
            state.camera.lookAt(markerRef.current.position.x , markerRef.current.position.y + 1  , markerRef.current.position.z  )            
            state.camera.position.lerp(vec.set(-4, 0, 0 ), 0.01)
            state.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
        }
        else if(!isContact){            
            state.camera.lookAt(markerRef.current.position.x , markerRef.current.position.y + 1 , markerRef.current.position.z )
            state.camera.position.lerp(vec.set(-3, 1.5, 4 ), 0.01)
            state.camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
        }
        return null
    })
    
    
    return (
        
        <primitive 
            object= { character.scene}
            position-y= {-1.2}
            ref={markerRef}
            
        />
        
        
    )
    
}
```

I also tried to add +2 at the z coordinate in the lookAt() function like so:

```
state.camera.lookAt(markerRef.current.position.x , markerRef.current.position.y + 1  , markerRef.current.position.z +2 )
```

The position is correct, but the problem is that the camera animation "bounces"

Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: I recommend using this for all r3f camera movement - https://github.com/yomotsu/camera-controls